# Why Is Image Exporting At Larger Dimensions Than In Illustrator File?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, images, resize, file-size, dimensions

This does not make sense to me. I have an Illustrator file and the shape is about 245 x 210 px on the artboard:

[image]

I then export this image as a transparent png, using the artboard:

[image] 
[image]

But after it's been exported to my desktop and I right click on it and get info, it says that the dimensions are 1036 x 915:

[image]

That's WAY different from how it is in Illustrator. And when I try to upload the image to imgur, it's also too large there as well:

https://i.imgur.com/AUuet7c.png

I'm just trying to make this triangle smaller. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are exporting at 300 ppi which is more for printing, for screens, I believe that the number is generally 72 ppi.

I personally would just use **Save for Web** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and then manually input the size I want in the dialog.

[image]